# What does the t in tapply stand for?

Tags: r, tapply

There seems to be general agreement that the l in "lapply" stands for list, the s in "sapply" stands for simplify and the r in "rapply" stands for recursively. But I could not find anything on the t in "tapply". I am now very curious.

Comment: No idea - `t` for `tabulating` the data into groups?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stands for `table` since `tapply` is the generic form of the `table` function.  You can see this by comparing the following calls:

```
x <- sample(letters, 100, rep=T)
table(x)
tapply(x, x, length)
```

although obviously `tapply` can do more than counting.

Also, some references that refer to "table-apply":

- [R and S Plus companion](https://books.google.com/books?id=xWS8kgRjGcAC&pg=PA137&dq=tapply+%22table+apply%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aRg3Vf2qDdamyAS8yIH4DQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=tapply%20%22table%20apply%22&f=false)
- [Modern Applied Biostatistical Methods](https://books.google.com/books?id=LRAnmrH86HcC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=tapply+%22table+apply%22&source=bl&ots=45lH_QeCKh&sig=68X7au4isPMIft0YYNMXk8Jfz_8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wPc2VbbUOvPisAT2p4CYAw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw)

Answer (score 5):

I think of it as 'table'-apply since the result comes as a matrix/table/array and its dimensions are established by the INDEX arguments. An R `table`-classed object is really very similar in contrcution and behavior to an R matrix or array.  The application is being performed in a manner similar to that of `ave`. Groups are first assembled on the basis of the "factorized" `INDEX` argument list (possibly with multiple dimensions) and a matrix or array is returned with the results of the `FUN` applied to each cross-classified grouping.

The other somewhat similar function is 'xtabs'. I keep thinking it should have a "FUN" argument, but what I'm probably forgetting at that point is really `tapply`.

Answer (score 2):

`tapply` is sort of the odd man out. As far as I know, and as far as the R documentation for the apply functions goes, the 't' does not stand for anything, unlike the other apply functions which indicate the input or output options.