# Naming / Names of the apply function family in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, mapply

I'm currently studying R. In particular I need to remember the functions in the `apply`-function family (e.g. `lapply`, `sapply`, `mapply`, etc.). I know what each function in the `apply`-function family does (especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family) helps a lot), but mix up the names from time to time.

Is there a natural meaning for the prefix of each apply function (like `lapply = 'list'-apply`)?

Comment: Yes -- `s` for simple in `sapply`, `m` for matrix in `mapply`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you got following `apply` r-basic functions:

- `apply` for apply ;)
- `lapply` for **lists** or vectors [(documentation)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply)
- `vapply` for specific return **value** [(documentation)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply)
- `sapply` for **simple** [(documentation)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply)
- `mapply` for **multiple** list or vector arguments [(documentation)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mapply)
- `tapply` for **table** (check old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785037/what-does-the-t-in-tapply-stand-for))
- `rapply` for **recursive** ([documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rapply))

I think you can interprete some prefix differently, like `m` was mentioned in the commentary as multivariate (commentary got removed). I tried to use the wording of the documentation, so it's more likely to be understood.

Also `lapply`, `sapply` and `vapply` are in the same documentation site, since the `sapply` and `vapply` are wrapper for `lapply`

Comment: i hope i did not forget any apply function. Tell me if i missed something.

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much sense and will definitely help me memorising. If I encounter even more apply variants, I'll get back to this answer!