# Do I need to reduce for-loop in R and how?

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, simulation, montecarlo

I am a freshman in R coding, but I've heard that loop in R is much slower than other language like Python or C. So do I need to reduce loop when coding in R?

Specifically, in this simulation code, how can I improve my poor coding skill?

```
library(moments)
n <- c(5:20)
m <- c(1:10000)
skew <- c()
kurt <- c()
for(num in n){
  beta1 <- c()
  beta2 <- c()
  for(i in m){
    set.seed(num * 10000 + i)
    x <- rnorm(num, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    beta1 <- c(beta1, skewness(x))
    beta2 <- c(beta2, kurtosis(x) - 3)
  }
  skew <- c(skew, quantile(beta1, probs = c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99, 1)))
  kurt <- c(kurt, quantile(beta2, probs = c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99, 1)))
}
```

Comment: Of each of your sample sizes you want kinda list of skew and kurt quantiles, i.e. 16 such lists?

Comment: For loops are not bad in R, but they can be mis-used. "Growing" an object in a loop is a bad habit, and will slow down your code. You are growing `beta1` and `beta2` in your inner loop - they get longer each iteration. It's much more efficient to allocate an empty vector of the appropriate length, and then fill in the holes. The free [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is excellent reading on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One main advantage of not using `for` loops in R is to exploit its vectorization. So while in languages like Python or C you code vector calculations for each element of a vector, in R you can conveniently code the calculation for the entire vector at once (see Edit below) and also reduce computation time by actually using fast underlying C, Fortran, etc. functions.

I would put all the calculations you want to do for a single sample size into a function `statFUN`  and put it into an `lapply` to loop over the vector of sample sizes `n`.

For the quantiles we either could use `apply` or `matrixStats::rowQuantiles` which I recommend because it's faster.

`set.seed()` should be needed just one time before running the `lapply`, all the `res`ults will be reproducible with that one seed.

```
n <- 5:20  ## different sample sizes
m <- 1e4   ## number of replications in each iteration
probs <- c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99, 1)

library(moments)
library(matrixStats)

statFUN <- function(i, num) {
  r <- replicate(i, {
    x <- rnorm(num, mean=0, sd=1)
    c(kurt=kurtosis(x) - 3, skew=skewness(x))
  })
  # t(apply(r, 1, quantile, probs=probs))  ## using base R
  rowQuantiles(r, probs=probs)  ## using matrixStats
}

set.seed(42)
res <- lapply(n, statFUN, m)
```

#### Result

The `res`ult is a list of the quantiles of kurtosis and skewness quantiles for each sample size.

```
res
# [[1]]
#               0%          1%         10%         20%
# kurt -0.04710729 -0.04658709 -0.04190536 -0.03670343
# skew -0.03045563 -0.02969417 -0.02284104 -0.01522645
#              50%          80%           90%         99%
# kurt -0.03388803 -0.006250622  1.068998e-03 0.007656657
# skew -0.01028591 -0.006132523 -5.883157e-05 0.005407491
#             100%
# kurt 0.008388619
# skew 0.006014860
# 
# [[2]]
#               0%          1%         10%         20%
# kurt -0.09089922 -0.08859363 -0.06784329 -0.04478737
# skew -0.03252828 -0.03165837 -0.02382918 -0.01513009
#               50%          80%        90%        99%
# kurt -0.023634727 -0.005277533 0.01038904 0.02448896
# skew  0.003433589  0.017711708 0.01947178 0.02105585
#            100%
# kurt 0.02605562
# skew 0.02123186
#
# [...]
```

where

```
length(res)
# [1] 16
```

#### Edit

Here a small example to better illustrate what is actually meant by vectorization in R. While in most programming languages the addition of two vectors is coded element-wise, in R the addition of vectors may be coded directly (i.e. in a vectorized manner).

```
a <- 1:9
b <- rev(a)

## element wise addition of vectors a and b
s1 <- c()
for (i in seq(a)) {
  s1[i] <- a[i] + b[i]
}
s1
# [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

## direct addition of vectors a and b (i.e. vectorized)
s2 <- a + b
s2
# [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Instead of `for` loops we may look into the `*apply` family. However, mostly there are still for-loops hidden in it. (To see function codes type e.g. `lapply` without brackets or anything.)

You might want to read e.g. those great Q&As:

- [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/6574038)
- [Naming / Names of the apply function family in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450738/naming-names-of-the-apply-function-family-in-r)
- [Why are loops slow in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7142767/6574038)
- [How to see the source code of R .Internal or .Primitive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035586/6574038)

**Note:** The vectorization is actually just the language feature of R. So-called "vectorized functions" often use C, Fortran, etc. code internally, in which you still find for-loops at the end, but in a much faster language, though. See for instance the [source code of `summary.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/summary.c) which is called when we use `sum()`.

Comment: Many thanks, but how can I learn to code with vectorization? Do I need to think like before first or write the vectorized code straightly?

Comment: @JamesYu I have rephrased my answer a bit to be clearer and added a small example on vectorization. Would that help?

Comment: The links you shared help me a lot!

Comment: @JamesYu Nice to know, have fun!